# System File Watcher and MFS/HFS+ networked drives

Tags: c#, .net, macos

I have used System File Watcher only on local drives and NTFS network drives.

Is Macintosh File System (MFS) or HFS+ supported?

If not then what can I do to monitor a MFS/HFS+ using .NET?

Comment: Do you really mean MFS? I think you mean HFS+ which is the native filesystem for Macs these days.

Comment: I really don't know exactly, I just got the request from my boss and he said MFS but he might mean HFS.